# Open the window from existing page in firefox gives me security error

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

I am developing a Firefox extension. On a client side of a web page I add a link and on clicking the link I intend to open a window where it will allow the user to type in text. When I click the link, it opens the window but it won't allow me to write to it.

e.g. 
`ww.document.write('<div id = "textDiv">') ;`
here it gives me an error:

`Error: uncaught exception: [Exception... "Security error"  code: "1000" nsresult: "0x805303e8 (NS_ERROR_DOM_SECURITY_ERR)"  location: "chrome://googbar/content/googbar.js Line: 272"]`

and I open window using the following:

```
var ww = Components.classes[
    "@mozilla.org/embedcomp/window-watcher;1"].getService(Components.interfaces.nsIWindowWatcher);
var wm =Components.classes["@mozilla.org/appshell/window-mediator;1"]

calWindow = ww.openWindow(null,'calendarWindow',null, 'left =500, top = 190, width = 230, height = 220,titlebar = no', null);
```

The window that is opened is not an empty window, it contains the contents of the parent window. for e.g I open this window from wikipedia, the new window opened contains the wiki page on it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely clear what's causing this, but these [two](https://developer.mozilla.org/Talk:en/XUL/Property/contentDocument) [pages](https://developer.mozilla.org/Talk:en/XUL_Tutorial/Tree_View_Details) on MDC suggest that this may have been affected by changes in Firefox 3.0 to tighten up some security issues.

Although not a complete answer, this might put you on the right track for solving your problem. If not, give us some more details about what you're trying to do.

Comment: with my extension i try to add a link, which on clicking opens a window and in this window the user can type in the text which will be saved in SQLite. So its like allowing user to annotate on the web page.

Comment: I even tried window.open which i suppose does the same thing but it give me the same error. This link that i am talking about is added on the Web page (Not as a tool bar)on the client side.

Answer (score 0):

1) [nsIWindowWatcher.openWindow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/nsIWindowWatcher#openWindow%28%29)'s second argument is URL. 'calendarWindow' isn't. A [google result from mozillazine](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?p=3307343#p3307343) suggests that passing '' magically makes document.write work, I didn't check.

2) I would try setting `document.body.innerHTML` instead of using `document.write()`. I think `document.write()` is a poor API that should only continue to exist for compatibility.

3) Anyway, in your case I don't see why you need to open a whole browser window just to put some simple HTML there. Create a XUL dialog, put it in your extension and open it (using `window.open('chrome://....', '', 'chrome')`). It's also much faster to open.